# i have to read file name in a folder by using flex.But i am taking some errors in the code .The following code is :

Tags: flash, file, apache-flex, file-io, filenames

I have to read file name in a folder by using flex.But i am taking some errors in the code .File is not defined.The following code is:

```
protected function myCBSelectedXMLs_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
                {

                try
                {
                    var fileName:String = new String();

                    if(myCBSelectedXMLs.selectedIndex == spark.components.ComboBox.CUSTOM_SELECTED_ITEM)
                        myCBSelectedXMLs.dataProvider.addItem(myCBSelectedXMLs.selectedItem);
                    Alert.show(myCBSelectedXMLs.selectedItem +" is selected", "Selection", Alert.OK);

                    var dir : File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("MyFolder");
                    dir.getDirectoryListingAsync();
                    dir.addEventListener(FileListEvent.DIRECTORY_LISTING,onDirectoryListComplete);
                } 
                catch(error:Error) 
                {
                    Alert.show("error", "Selection", Alert.OK);

                }

            }
```

Comment: The problem is that code gives error so file is not accepted

Comment: Care to share what the error message is? The `Error` object has a `message` property that will help us determine what your problem is. Without that, we can only guess.  Try this in your `catch` block: `Alert.show(error.message, "Error", Alert.OK);`

Comment: the error is : Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: File

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the part of your code mentioned below:

```
var dir : File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("MyFolder");

dir.getDirectoryListingAsync();
```

check if "MyFolder" exists.

As told by Sunil, *error.message* might help you in this.

Comment: Besides these,when I add library of 'import flash.filesystem.File;' , I am taking this error that is 'The import filesystem could not be found.'.

Answer (score 0):

`File` (and the entire `flash.filesystem` package) is available **only** for AIR apps. You do not say you are creating an AIR app so I am guessing that you are not. Those packages do not exist for non-AIR apps and are not usable by non-AIR apps if you do manage to find the correct files. On the web, Adobe has incredibly strict security procedures and you, as a developer, have absolutely zero access to the file system without the user initiating that access.

From Adobe's LiveDocs for [`flash.filesystem`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/package-detail.html) (emphasis mine):

> The flash.filesystem package contains classes used in accessing the filesystem. This package is **only available to content running in Adobe AIR**.

You can look at `FileReference` which will allow the user to choose a file to load/save, but that is the extent of what you can do there. You may also want to look at using a `SharedObject` if the data you need to save/read is small (<100kb).